# no iFrame transparency in IE?

Tags: css

I have an iFrame that uses a background image on behind it.  On Firefox, the background is transparent and I can see the background image.  On IE the background in the Iframe defaults to white.  Is there a fix for this?

Example:

```
<td width="80px" class="voting" align="center"><div id="votingIframeDiv">
    <iframe  id="votingIframe" frameborder="0"  allowTransparency="true" vspace="0"  hspace="0"  marginwidth="0"  marginheight="0" width="80"  height="70" scrolling="no"  src="vote/index.php?userid=89&fishid=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" >
        </iframe></div>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure both the `IFRAME` and its source `BODY` element have a `background:transparent` style rule applied:

```
<iframe  id="votingIframe" frameborder="0"  allowTransparency="true" style="background:transparent" ... ></iframe>
```

and in the source:

```
<body style="background:transparent">
```

PS: CSS styles above are inline just for example.

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary, as the default value is `transparent` already

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a fix for this?

Yes, IE has the non-standard [`allowtransparency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property.

```
<IFRAME ID="Frame1" SRC="transparentBody.htm" allowTransparency="true">
</IFRAME>
```

Comment: @user which element has the background image?

Comment: The parent page gas a background image applied to the body.  The Iframe allows the transparency in Firefox but not IE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can fix this but it also depends upon the iframe's origin's style sheets, If the iframe's source has a bg set in CSS this will override `allowTransparency="true"`

This may be a long shot but try putting `allowTransparency="true"` at the end of the iframe tag.

*Note:* In my testing `allowTransparency` has not worked in IE6.

Comment: In my testing it has never worked, That said it is in a VM so... this could be give/take but I am doubtful it would make a difference. @Pekka edited my above statement

Answer (score 0):

After putting allowTransparency='true' if you're not getting any love try making sure that your style="background:transparent"  .